# TypeError while running Debug APK for React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, typeerror

[TypeError screen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92iw3.jpg)

After installing the generated Debug APK when the Android app is opened it shows the above screen. After reloading from the server (`react-native start`), the error screen goes. How can I solve this problem so the app does not show the error. Please answer the question.

Comment: Can you please add your code ?

Comment: i don't know which part is generating the error. I could not share whole source code @KishanBharda

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to show some data that doen't exist yet, 
Are you using any state management ? or multiple screen ?, 
try to fetch all your data on the first screen this can avoid the error.

Comment: Debug-apk requires development server to run.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer. Development Server must be run to run Debug APK.